# Core Data Perform() performAndWait() not sure 100% about

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am a bit unsure if I have understand the concept of perform() and performAndWait() functions in Core Data.

We can have 2 types of contexts:

```
1) .mainQueueConcurrencyType (main Queue)
2) .privateQueueConcurrencyType (background Queue)
```

For both contexts, I can understand the purpose of performAndWait()
It waits to execute the block code and then continues.

For the privateQueueConcurrencyType the documents says:

```
The NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType configuration creates its own queue upon initialization and can be used only on that queue. Because the queue is private and internal to the NSManagedObjectContext instance, it can only be accessed through the performBlock: and the performBlockAndWait: methods.
```

But what is the purpose of perform() in mainQueue??

when we have a context on mainQueue and we update/delete/what-ever a NSManagedObject isn't that happening on the mainQueue anyway? What is the purpose of perform() then?

Comment: One advantage is that you do not have to care on which queue you currently are. CoreData handles it for you.

Comment: But do I have to use perform() when I am updating a NSManagedObject inside the context (main) ?? Does it make any difference?

Comment: No. You do not have to.

Answer (score 7):

> When we have a context on mainQueue and we update/delete/what-ever a NSManagedObject isn't that happening on the mainQueue anyway?

What if you call those methods from some other queue? If code is executing on some other queue, it can call `perform` or `performBlockAndWait` on a managed object context that uses main queue concurrency. The code in that closure executes on the main queue even though the calling code is not on the main queue.

For example:

```
let customQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queuename")
customQueue.async { 
    // ... do some stuff ..
    mainQueueContext.performAndWait {
        // ... do some stuff on the main queue ...
    }
    // ... do some more stuff ...
}
```